# Can't submit ajax form Internal error 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have submit problem with code below. On Firebug I get this message:

POST localhost:9706/Home/Upload  500 Internal Server Error

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

This form I can submit but without jquery and unobtrusive-ajax scripts and in that case submit looks like normal submit (whole page submit, without ajax)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<FileInfoModel>>"%> 

 <%@ Import Namespace="MembershipTest.Models"%> 
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"type="text/javascript"</script>   
<script type="text/javascript">     
function OnSuccess(response) {
     alert(response);
 }
 function OnFailure(response) {
     alert("Whoops! That didn't go so well did it?");  
 }   </script>   
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", null,
     new AjaxOptions
     {
         HttpMethod = "POST",
         UpdateTargetId = "uploadTable",
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
         OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
         OnFailure = "OnFailure" 
     },
     new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){%>  
  <fieldset> 
  <legend> Upload File: </legend> <span>Filename:</span>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> 
  </fieldset> <% } %>  
  <div id="uploadTable"></div>
```

**Controller code**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {

        List<FileInfoModel> FilesInfoData =  new List<FileInfoModel>();

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(uploadLocation));
        var files = from f in dir.GetFiles()
                    select f;
        foreach (var i in files)
        {
            FileInfoModel fmodel = new FileInfoModel(){
                Name = i.Name,
                Length = i.Length,
                LastWriteTime = i.LastWriteTime
            };
            FilesInfoData.Add(fmodel);
        }

        return PartialView("Upload",FilesInfoData);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileWrapper file)
    {

        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var saveLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(uploadLocation), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(saveLocation);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Model code**

```
public class FileInfoModel
{
    public FileInfoModel(){}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastWriteTime { get; set; }       
}
```

Comment: Well, obviously, it's a server side error. I think you should show us that code or debug yourself. Compare input of the normal submit against the input of the Ajax request and see what's the difference. Then find out how your script responds to that difference.

Comment: Ok I added controllers and models code. I can't catch what is wrong with this code and not now how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something similar yesterday and i got the same error when i used ajax.beginform so insted of that use ..

```
<form action="Home/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                       
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />                       
</form>
```

try this in ur view side this may help..

Comment: I know for your solution but I need to post that form with ajax because have to make form which can upload files (or do whatever) without reload entire page

Comment: hii .. did u find the solution .. can u paste it here ..!!thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is expecting a httpget bit your form is using post. If you remove the httpget from the controller action it should work.

Comment: It's not true because I post data to action which have [HttpPost]. Also I try your suggestion but it not work for me